# CSS field name attribute mask

Tags: css, regex, attributes

I have few fields with name attributes like:

```
fields[some_name][1][indicator]
fields[some_name][2][indicator]
...
fields[some_name][N][indicator]
```

how can I code **CSS** style for all such fields like:

```
input[name='fields[some_name][*][indicator]'] {...}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
input[name^='fields[some_name]'][name$='[indicator]'] {...}
```

Or even more restricted:

```
input[name^='fields[some_name]['][name$='][indicator]'] {...}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! As I see this two conditions say 'begins with' and 'ends with' like regexp.